# rasa.core.agent - Could not load model due to Failed to find module 'rasa.nlu.classifiers.fallback_classifier

Tags: python, docker, rasa-nlu, rasa

I'm dockerizing rasa application and the `Dockerfile` is

```
FROM python:3.7.6

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends build-essential curl

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY entrypoint.sh .

COPY src/ .

EXPOSE 5005

ENTRYPOINT ["/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

The content of `entrypoint.sh` is

```
#!/bin/sh

exec "$@"
```

and the `requirements.txt` file has

```
rasa==1.10.14
```

I initiated a rasa application using `rasa init` command outside docker inside `src` directory and copied all to the docker.

Now when I run rasa using

```
docker build -t image .
docker run -it image rasa run
```

It gives the following error

```
2020-10-15 19:38:00 INFO     root  - Starting Rasa server on http://localhost:5005
2020-10-15 19:38:02 ERROR    rasa.core.agent  - Could not load model due to Failed to find module 'rasa.nlu.classifiers.fallback_classifier'.
No module named 'rasa.nlu.classifiers.fallback_classifier'.
Experienced exception while trying to serve
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rasa/nlu/registry.py", line 173, in get_component_class
    return class_from_module_path(component_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rasa/utils/common.py", line 210, in class_from_module_path
    m = importlib.import_module(module_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rasa.nlu.classifiers.fallback_classifier'
...
```

Running the rasa outside docker is working fine.